# How can I use a external .js file for Acrobat Scripting?

Tags: javascript, api, acrobat

I'm using Adobe Acrobat DC to create several PDF forms.
Sometimes I write the same Javascript code in different PDF Files, so How can I write a single .js file with the regular functions related to several PDF Files in order not to rewrite same function each time for each file?

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat JavaScript does not have a "include" function.

In order to have a central "library" for your forms, you have, however, some possibilities:

• If you have control over your users' machine: Application-level script file (also known as Folder-level). Create a file with all your functions, give it the .js suffix and save it at the appropriate location (note this location varies with the Acrobat/Reader version as well as with the platform. Because this is a file which every of your users has to install, it may be too complicated.

• For your developments: Document-level JavaScript transfer file: Create a PDF with all the document-level JavaScripts you need. This document consists of one single page. In order to get those document-level scripts into your form, add this page to the form, and immediately remove it. This will leave the document-level scripts in the form.

• For dynamically adapted scripts: FDF: Accordingly constructed FDFs can be used to add scripts into a form.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How may I know where the appropiate directory is? I have seen somethibg little about folder level scripts before. I do not know if I am missleading, but I saw something about: app.getPath("app","javascript"); Is that the directory where I have to put "myfunctions.js" file? I placed there and it did not work.