# How can one use a JavaScript library in an Acrobat JavaScript script?

Tags: javascript, libraries, acrobat-sdk

I am writing an [Acrobat Javascript script](https://evermap.com/javascript.asp). How can one use a JavaScript library in an Acrobat JavaScript script?

Comment: What library are you trying to use? Is `npm` involved at all?

Comment: @Dai thanks, I'm curious  for any JS library. I.e., I'm curious about the cases where npm is involved and the cases where npm is not involved.

Comment: Possible dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451977/include-js-library-into-pdf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67039534/how-can-i-use-a-external-js-file-for-acrobat-scripting

Comment: You can write it in newer JavaScript and then transpile it back to ES5 using something like webpack

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks, that's an interesting idea, you're welcome to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @SuperStormer thanks, both links seem to be the case where the Acrobat Javascript script is embedded in a PDF.